# Inserting a div into another static div for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a WordPress site and I want to add second header line after the mobile header div.

When I insert the code in Chrome console with device toolbar as a mobile device, it works perfectly.

```
$(".headerMobileDiv").append("<div class='container'> Sample Text </div>");
```

However when I try to add this code into header or footer section, it doesn't work. There is no problem with the implementation of js code.

Comment: It sounds like you need to put your code in a document.ready event handler, or execute it just before the `</body>`  tag

Comment: Is there any error in the console on your mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".headerMobileDiv").append("<div class='container'> Sample Text </div>");
});
```

By default, JavaScript doesn't know when to execute: you have to tell it when. This example will execute on `$(document).ready()` which means when the page is done loading.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to wrap in something like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".headerMobileDiv").append("<div class='container'> Sample Text </div>");
});
```

the element you're trying to append to may not have loaded yet